# Google Custom App Publishing API from NodeJS server: apkInvalidFile

Tags: google-play-developer-api

When using the Google Custom App Publishing API from my NodeJS, I encounter an error

```
config: [Object: Inspection interrupted prematurely. Maximum call stack size exceeded.],
   code: 403,
   errors: [
     {
       domain: 'global',
       reason: 'forbidden',
       message: 'apkInvalidFile'
     }
   ]
```

And no much more details about it.

Answer (score 0):

There is a very precise way to create this request. The right way is not documented anywhere and requires some retro-engineering.
Here is what works:

```
result = await getPlayCustomApp().accounts.customApps.create({
  account: 'FIXME entreprise developer account id',
  requestBody: {
    title: 'Trololo app title',
    languageCode: 'en_US',
  },
  media: {
    body: fs.createReadStream('/path/to/app.apk'),
  },
});
```

I hope it helps people not waste their afternoon!